# I need faster methods to optimize my loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops, optimization

So, I'm a python newbie looking for someone with an ideia on how to optimize my code. I'm working with a spreadsheet with over 6000 rows, and this portion of my code seems really ineficient.

```
for x in range(0,len(df):
  if df.at[x,'Streak_currency'] != str(df.at[x,'Currency']):
      df.at[x, 'Martingale']  = df.at[x-1, 'Martingale'] + (df.at[x-1, 'Martingale'] )/64
      x+=1
      if df.at[x,'Streak_currency'] == str(df.at[x,'Currency']):
        x+=1
```

It can take upwards of 8 minutes run.
With my limited knowledge, I only manage to change my df.loc for df.at, and it helped a lot. But I st

**UPDATE**

In this section of the code, I'm trying to apply a function based on a previous value until a certain condition is met, in this case,
 ***df.at[x,'Streak_currency'] != str(df.at[x,'Currency']):***

I really don't know why this iteration is taking so long. In theory, it should only look at a previous value and apply the function. Here is a sample of the output:

> `Periodo Currency  ... Agrupamento  Martingale
>   0           1   GBPUSD   1    1.583720 <--- starts aplying a function over and over.
>   1           1   GBPUSD   1    1.608466
>   2           1   GBPUSD   1    1.633598
>   3           1   GBPUSD   1    1.659123
>   4           1   GBPUSD   1    1.685047
>   5           1   GBPUSD   1    1.711376 <- stops aplying, since Currency changed
>   6           1   EURCHF   2    1.256550 
>   7           1   USDCAD   3    1.008720 <- starts applying again until currency changes
>   8           1   USDCAD   3    1.024481
>   9           1   USDCAD   3    1.040489
>   10          1   GBPAUD   4    1.603080`

Comment: I don't think the ```x+=1``` in your code inside the loop does anything useful, especially the one on the currency condition, because the ```x``` gets its new value every iteration never caring what value you added . You can try that example to get the idea of what I'm talking about
```
for i in range(0,10):
...     print(i)
...     i += 1
```

Comment: if you could explain what you trying to achieve from this loop, it would  make things clear for anyone to contribute an answer for your question

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply  @KareemEmad! I tryed updating the post so you can have a better ideia of what I'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Pandas lookups like `df.at[x,'Streak_currency']` are not efficient. Indeed, for each evaluation of this kind of expression (multiple time per loop iteration), pandas fetch the column regarding its name and then fetch the value in a list.
You can avoid this computation cost by just storing the columns in variables before the loop. Additionally, you can put the column in numpy array so the value can be fetch in a more efficient way (assuming all the value have the same type).
Finally, using string conversions and string comparisons on integers are not efficient. They can be avoided here (assuming the integers are not unreasonably big).

Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
streakCurrency = np.array(df['Streak_currency'], dtype=np.int64)
currency = np.array(df['Currency'], dtype=np.int64)
martingale = np.array(df['Martingale'], dtype=np.float64)
for x in range(len(df)):
    if streakCurrency[x] != currency[x]:
        martingale[x] = martingale[x-1] * (65./64.)
        x+=1
        if streakCurrency[x] == currency[x]:
            x+=1
# Update the pandas dataframe
df['Martingale'] = martingale
```

This should at least an order of magnitude faster.

Please note that the second condition is useless since the compared values cannot be equal and different at the same times (this may be a bug in your code)...